# Issues about C# connecting to EC2

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-ec2

I am currently using Amazon EC2 (AMI linux) + MySQL, and now I am working on C# stuff.

I wrote code like this:

```
        MySqlConnection DBConn = new MySqlConnection();
        DBConn.ConnectionString = "Server=ec2-**.compute-1.amazonaws.com;Database=****;uid=root;password=****;port=3306;charset=utf8";

        try
        {
            DBConn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("connecting fail");
        }
```

But for some reason, when I run this, it generates a 'connecting fail' error.

I googled and figured out that I need to set "grant all privileges *.* to root@'localhost' "

So, I did that!

But it still doesn't work. I think I followed all of the steps though.

- I am working on Visual studio 2008 & Windows7 at the moment.
- I Checked the error and it seems like it's a timeout error. I think it's a firewall thing but don't know what I should do. I set my security group so the TCP ports are opened to all (incl. Mysql). It's still not working. Isn't that the way to solve this problem?;( 
  However, the thing that I am curious about is that I could access to the database using MySQL workbench before I set the security group.

Sorry that I am totally new to EC2.

Comment: Could you reomove the try catch, let the exception fire and paste the error and stack trace

Comment: As noted, check the firewall nd (since this is ec2) make sure the port is open in your security group as well.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should open MySQL port on your server via aws console. you can do it by clicking  by go to DB Security Groups on RDS section, and just put CIDR:0.0.0.0/0 to test you are connected and status is authorized. Then you can rearrange rules to specify which ip can connect.
 2) You should use MySQL connector to connect MySQL from C#.
[Mysql Connector Link](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
 3) Your connection string should be like :

```
Server=yourdburl;
Database=yourdb; 
Uid=yourdbuser; 
Pwd=yourdbuserpassword;
charSet=utf8;
```

3rd one seems right, you should check 1st and 2nd cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn on [VPC Flow Logs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/) on that ENI to see if the connection is getting accepted on that interface, or rejected. High chance that your security groups are no correct, as gandil mentioned.